# Instantiating an object in a file VS in a struct

Tags: go, design-patterns, backend, go-gin

I was reading this blog recently and I saw something interesting. The object instance is initialized in the file itself and then accessed everywhere. I found it pretty convenient and was wondering if it's the best practice.
[https://dev.to/hackmamba/build-a-rest-api-with-golang-and-mongodb-gin-gonic-version-269m#:~:text=setup.go%20file%20and%20add%20the-,snippet%20below,-%3A](https://dev.to/hackmamba/build-a-rest-api-with-golang-and-mongodb-gin-gonic-version-269m#:%7E:text=setup.go%20file%20and%20add%20the-,snippet%20below,-%3A)

I'm more used to a pattern where we first create a struct like so:

```
type Server struct {
    config     util.Config
    store      db.Store
    tokenMaker token.Maker
    router     *gin.Engine
}
```

and then set eveything in main:

```
func NewServer(config util.Config, store db.Store) (*Server, error) {
    tokenMaker, err := token.NewPasetoMaker(config.TokenSymmetricKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("cannot create token maker: %w", err)
    }

    server := &Server{
        config:     config,
        store:      store,
        tokenMaker: tokenMaker,
    }

    server.setupRouter()
    return server, nil
}
```

and then the server object is passed every where.

What's best? Is it okay to use the pattern mentioned in that blog?

Thank you.

I tried to implement both patterns, The pattern mentioned in the blog seems very convenient to use as I'm not passing around objects and can easily access object I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow any one of those patterns. But, I think it's better to pass the object pointer everywhere necessary. It saves lots of work and ensures that the object is always updated.